# What part of speech is the first "command" word in the following sentences that have a quote:

Tags: parts-of-speech

Consider the following sentences:

> - The guard said, "Roll the stone away from here."
> - The King said, "Bow down before me."
> - Tell my soul, "Flee like a bird from the mountain of sorrow."

What part of speech are the words *roll, bow* and *flee*? Are they nouns or verbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are unconjugated verbs (infinitives):

> To **roll** the stone.
>
> To **bow** before the king.
>
> To **flee** like a bird.

Comment: I don't think you should call it the "infinitive". All the examples are *imperatives*, with implied/deleted subject ***You***. And *infinitive* and *imperative* are essentially ["verb moods"](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/english-grammar-101-verb-mood/), not "tenses" or "conjugations".